# How to compare if the difference of 2 times is greater than 2 hours

Tags: php, datetime, compare, diff

I have to compare if result from a subtraction is greater on less than 2 hours. I don't know how exactly do make this comparison. I tried the following. It is correct for the third if, but for the first and second result is not correct.

Here's my view:

```html
 <?php
    $transport= new DateTime($row->transportDate);
    $max=new DateTime(max($forecast_array));
    $interval = $transport->diff($max);

    if($max->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') < $transport->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') && $interval->format('%h:%i:%s') >= '2:00:00' ) {     
     
    echo '<img src="<?= base_url();?>/assets/images/tick.png">';
     } 
     if($max->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') < $transport->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') && $interval->format('%h:%i:%s') < '2:00:00' ) {    
     
   echo '<img src="<?= base_url();?>/assets/images/warning.png">';
    }
     if($max->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') > $transport->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')) { 
    
    echo '<img src="<?= base_url();?>/assets/images/forbidden.png">';
      } ?>
```

Edited: Now, I'm using this code: Is it correct?

```html
<?php
$transport = strtotime($row->transportDate); 
$max = strtotime(max($forecast_array));
$interval = abs($max - $transport); 

if($max < $transport &&  $interval >= 2 * 60 * 60 ) {     
                       
   echo '<img src="<?= base_url();?>/assets/images/tick.png">';
}
```

Comment: I changed your title since it read weird before. I don't think I changed the meaning if I understood the question correctly.

Comment: Yes, I mean that. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know PHP :/

Comment: Np, just another tip. From what I *can* tell, a lot of the code you posted isn't directly related to the question (subtracting and comparing times). Try to reduce the amount of code you post to include only the relevant parts; unless you feel that extra context is necessary. Throwing down too much code can discourage people from answering.

Comment: Have you tried using time stamps? Timestamps are HIGHLY useful for this, and it also is easier to determine how much time is between two time periods.

Comment: You can either use, `strtotime($DateString)`, `time()`. or since your are using the `DateTime` class, you can do `$DateTime::getTimeStamp();` Then compare the times and check to see if the time is greater than 2 hours. http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.gettimestamp.php

Comment: This will work but maybe you could write this using OOP?
Imho DateTime was correct way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To compare date/time differences as simple as your example, I'd suggest to not use the DateTime() class, but use simple timestamps.
E.g.:

```
$transport = strtotime($row->transportDate); // strtotime parses the time if it is not a timestamp, if it already is just use as is, i.e. without strtotime()
$max = strtotime(max($forecast_array));
$intervall = abs($max - $transport); 
// $intervall is now the difference in seconds therefore you can do this simple check:
if($interval >= 2 * 60 * 60){ // 2 hours à 60 minutes à 60 seconds
    // interval > 2 hours
} else {
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 $transport= new DateTime($row->transportDate);
 $max=new DateTime(max($forecast_array));
 $interval = $transport->diff($max);

 if ($interval->h > 2) {
     //
 }
```

Comment: I found this solution now: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6370538/php-greater-than-certain-time  I added int() - (int) $interval->format('%h:%i:%s') < '2' Is this the correct way?

Comment: Thank you all! This solution works, too: $interval->format('%h') < 2

Comment: Using format method the result will be a string but we have the integer in comparison statement. It works but there will be an unnecessary casting execution.

Comment: E edited my question and I posted my current code. Is this way correct to compare $transport and $max without using any format method? :) Thank you all!